# Audio driver conflict between nVidia and Realtek

Tags: windows-7, audio, drivers, graphics-card, nvidia-geforce

I bought a ASUS M5A99FX PRO R2.0 motherboard with integrated Realtek audio. I have a MSI GeForce GTX 960 Gaming with HD output that has Nvidia HD drivers installed. Somehow my audio outputs on my motherboard doesn't work, and I suspect it has to do with the nVidia drivers.

The computer doesn't show any errors in Device Manager. The listed audio adapters are my Realtek and nVidia. I have tried uninstalling (with deleting drivers), reinstalling etc. without any luck. I have also tried to disable nVidia HD sound through nVidia control panel.

Any ideas what might be wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: What makes you think it's a driver conflict? Have you even selected the correct output device?

Comment: @qasdfdsaq I was sure it was a driver conflict, and it seems like it was between some versions. Cause I tried to uninstall and reinstall back  and forth, but suddenly it worked. Try the ones on the motherboard website first, then try directly from manufacturer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it working. Uninstalled both GFX and sound drivers. Downloaded the latest drivers from Realtek through motherboard website. Downloaded latest GFX drivers from manufacturer. It's working now. You should have both Realtek and Nvidia HD audio in Device Manager, and it will still work. Just make sure to select "Speakers" (Realtek High Definition Audio) under Sound Management.